# app crash due to [uitextfield resignFirstResponder]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

There are three `textFields` in the view, as shown in image below:

[image]

when i click one of these textfields,one `textField` can `becomeFirstResponder`,then the keyboard appeared.not crash.
when i click the 'Done' or make the one of these textfields
`resignFirstResponder`,the keyboard will disappeared.but when
the keyboard disappeared, my app crash it.

Error:

> *iOS 8:* [UICompatibilityInputViewController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fd6b6074dd0
>
> *iOS 9:* [UIInputWindowController parentViewController]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fde7c004400
>
> *iOS 10:* [UICompatibilityInputViewController retain]...

Comment: Add the related code please

Comment: We don't know what UICompatibilityInputViewController and UIInputWindowController are.  Are they edible?

Comment: Check your textFieldShouldReturn(_:) method doing some action in it.

Comment: to be frank, I also don't know who they are.I see the apple Documentation and API Reference, I only find a property about UIInputViewController. I also not find UICompatibilityInputViewController and UIInputWindowController. the Xcode crash Log this.Now, I am so confused.

Comment: hello, I used a 'IQKeyboardManager' framework. i only use xib added three textField in the view. the 'IQKeyboardManager' will help me do the rest things.in the appeared keyboard, will have a 'done' flag that if i click it ,it will retreat the keyboard. then my app crash.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
and also set the delegates of the text fields

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
if (theTextField == yourTextFieldOne) {
    [theTextField becomeFirstResponder];
} else if (theTextField == yourTextFieldTwo) {
    [self.textPassword becomeFirstResponder];
}else if (theTextField == yourTextFieldThree) {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I will try it. I used the 'IQKeyboardManager' framework, It does not matter?

Comment: I only use a xib added three textFields,not do other things,why the keyboard disappeared, my app crash.and in different systems,iOS8,iOS9,iOS10，different errors  occurred. I am so confused.

Comment: I remove the 'IQKeyboardManager' framework,and set the delegate of the text fields. and use your code,but still crash.crash the same place.

Comment: thanks, I think of some way to make the problem reproduction.

Comment: Click on the blank to exit the keyboard, or click 'Done' to exit the keyboard. My app still crash.I think my code is ok.my project is so magical.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupBackBtn];
    // 初始化导航条
    [self setupNav];
    //点击空白  收回键盘
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(keyboardHide:)];
    tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    _confirmBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5.f;
}
```

Comment: Remove the tap gesture method and use my code sir. May be it will helps you a lot.

Comment: I  removed the tap gesture method and used your code.But, it do not work.my app still crash. I find a regular pattern that if my view need textfield,and the keyboard appeared, when the keyboard disappeared,my app will crash.all the view that have the textfield.oh my god. the error is the same.sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // 设置导航条
- (void)setupNav {
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    titleLabel.text = @"忘记密码";
    titleLabel.textColor = HexColor(0x795033);
    //    titleLabel.font = HNLightFont(20.0);
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];
    [titleLabel sizeToFit];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;

    // 这2句代码起到向下偏移64的作用
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```